# Append a dependency's cflags with meson-build

Tags: c++, conan, meson-build

I have a project that uses `meson-build` as a build system. The project dependencies are provided via the `conan` package manager in the form of package-config files. I struggle to append custom `cflags` to the dependencies.

Consider the following example. My project depends on `poco`. I use `conan` to manage this dependency and to create the .pc file:

```
prefix=/home/user/.conan/data/poco/1.12.1/_/_/package/4c07c9d602a0b548ed49892e5375a64ff54db11d
libdir=${prefix}/lib
includedir=${prefix}/include

Name: poco-poco_foundation
Description: Conan package: poco-poco_foundation
Version: 1.12.1
Libs: -L"${libdir}" -lPocoFoundation  -lpthread  -ldl  -lrt  -Wl,-rpath,"${libdir}"
Cflags: -I"${includedir}" -DPOCO_STATIC=ON -DPOCO_UNBUNDLED
Requires: libpcre2 zlib
```

I add this dependency to my build using the following line in `meson.build` file:

```
poco_foundation_dep = dependency('poco_foundation')
```

This works as intended. However, I would like to suppress a warning on this dependency by adding `-Wno-sign-compare` to the cflags. I fail to find a way to do this.

In my mind, I would like to do

```
poco_foundation_dep.cflags += -Wno-sign-compare
```

Please note that I don't want to modify the .pc files created by `conan` since they are automatically generated.

Comment: If this flag belongs to the consumer project, can't be added to the Meson files directly? Otherwise, the ``MesonToolchain`` is what should be used to add flags. You can also try directly from configuration ``tools.build:cxxflags`` can be defined in your ``[conf]`` in profile to inject compiler flags (to all packages, unless you say ``pkg*:tools.build:cxxflags``)

Comment: I tried to add `tools.build:cxxflags` in my conan profile, but I think this has not been implemented yet for the pkg_config generator. The additional flags were not applied to the generated .pc files. I might need to read up on the MesonToolchain again. I was under the impression that this is only useful when packaging a library with conan. I only use conan to install dependencies for a meson-build project.

Comment: Yes, the ``pkg_config`` generator is legacy, superseded by ``PkgConfigDeps``, the later implements the``tools.build:cxxflags`` conf, but not the legacy one.

Comment: I updated conan to 1.52.0 and replaced `pkg_config` by `PkgConfigDeps` in my `conanfile.txt`. Then I added a conan profile like this `[conf]
tools.build:cflags += -Wno-sign-compare` and ran `conan install` with the profile. Conan correctly reports that the configuration was set. Alas the `*.pc` do not pick up the flag, regardless of what I enter in the conan profile.

Comment: It is not very clear, you want to apply the build flags to the build of Poco package or to your own package? Maybe it is better to create an issue in Github https://github.com/conan-io/conan